# pysimplesoap, urllib2, requests

Tags: python, urllib2, python-requests

I'm trying to write a simple utility to pass an XML file to a URL and get a result.  I'm using python and have tried requests, urllib2 and simplesoap, all in simplistic fashion as my contact told me all I need to do is invoke the API.  Every time I try, I get a 500 error returned.

I can do requests.get, requests.headers and retrieve a response.

Any thoughts on why I would not be able to post this way?

code

```
import requests
url = "http://myurl.com/webrouter.asmx"
data = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><Envelope version="01.00"><tag>blah blah blah</tag></Envelope>"

r = requests.post(url, data)
```

Comment: a 500 is an error on the receiving end, you might want to ask your contact to check his logs...

Anything else in the response except for the status code?

Comment: Do you need to authenticate?

Comment: Hi rh0dium, there is no authentication required.  Per my contact, I should just be able to invoke the service and upload the XML.